# How to test methods in eclipse through JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I just learned the the unit testing this week and I'm supposed to find the at least a bug in the following piece of code. I have done some unit testing, but I'm not sure how I can actually find the bug. Every test that I have done has turned out correct so far. If someone can help me by showing me how I'm supposed to find the bug, I would greatly appreciate in advance.

The give code is:

```
 import java.util.Calendar;
 public class Time {





  private static final int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
  private static final int MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
  private static final int SECONDS_PER_HOUR = 3600;
  private static final int HOURS_PER_DAY = 24;



  private int hours;
  private int minutes;
  private int seconds;


  /**
   * Creates a Time object representing the current time.
   */
  public Time()
  {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    hours = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutes = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    seconds = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
  }


  /**
   * Creates a Time object representing a user-specified time.
   *
   * Note that the hours component must be specified using the
   * 24-hour clock.
   *
   * @param h hours
   * @param m minutes
   * @param s seconds
   *
   */
  public Time(int h, int m, int s)
  {

      setHours(h);
      setMinutes(m);
      setSeconds(s);
  }


  /**
   * Creates a Time object representing a user-specified time.
   *
   * The time is supplied as a string containing two integer values
   * representing hours and minutes or three integer values representing
   * hours, minutes and seconds, hours being specified using the 24-hour
   * clock in either case. The values must be separated from each other by
   * a colon.
   *
   * @param timeString string containing hours, minutes and seconds
   * 
   */
  public Time(String timeString)
  {
    String[] parts = timeString.split(":");
    if (parts.length < 2 || parts.length > 3) {

        System.out.println("invalid time ");
    }
    else{

    setHours( Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
    setMinutes( Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
    setSeconds( Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
    }
  }


  /**
   * @return Hours component of this time
   */
  public int getHours()
  {
    return hours;
  }


  /**
   * @return Minutes component of this time
   */
  public int getMinutes()
  {
    return minutes;
  }


  /**
   * @return Seconds component of this time
   */
  public int getSeconds()
  {
    return seconds;
  }


  /**
 * @param hours the hours to set
 */
public void setHours(int hours) {
    if (hours < 0 || hours > HOURS_PER_DAY) {
       //System.out.println("invalid  hours number");
        this.hours = 1;
    }
    else{
        this.hours = hours;
    }

}


/**
 * @param minutes the minutes to set
 */
public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
    if (minutes < 0 || minutes >= MINUTES_PER_HOUR){
        //System.out.println("invalid  minutes number");
        this.minutes = 1;
    }
    else{
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

}


/**
 * @param seconds the seconds to set
 */
public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
    if (seconds < 0 || seconds >= SECONDS_PER_MINUTE) {
        //System.out.println("invalid  seconds number");
        this.seconds = 1;
    }
    else{
    this.seconds = seconds;
    }
}


/**
   * Formats this time as a string containing hours, minutes and seconds.
   *
   * Leading zeroes are added to values if necessary and components are
   * separated from each other by a colon.
   *
   * @return String representation of this time
   */
   public String getTimeString()
  {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds());
  }


  /**
   * Expresses this time as a single integer value - the number of seconds
   * since midnight.
   *
   * @return Number of seconds
   */
  public int inSeconds()
  {
    int hourSec = SECONDS_PER_HOUR * hours;
    int minSec = SECONDS_PER_MINUTE * minutes;
    return hourSec + minSec + seconds;
  }


  /**
   * Creates a Time object advanced in time relative to this one by
   * a user-specified number of seconds.
   *
   * @param sec number of seconds to advance
   * @return String object advanced in time relative to this one
   * 
   */
  public String getTimePlus(int sec)
  {
      int h = 0;
      int m = 0;
      int s = 0;
      int future = 0;
      int remainder = 0;
    if (sec < 0) {
     System.out.println("invalid number of seconds");
    }
    else {
       future = this.inSeconds() + sec;
       h = (future / SECONDS_PER_HOUR) % HOURS_PER_DAY;
       remainder = future % SECONDS_PER_HOUR;
       m = remainder / SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
       s = remainder % SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

    }
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",h, m, s);
  }

}
```

The test code that I have written is:

```
 import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

 import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TestTime {
 private Time test;
@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws Exception {
    test = new Time(2, 45, 23);
}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() throws Exception {
    test = null;
}

@Test
public void constructorHourNegativeNegative() {
    Time t = new Time(-1, 35, 40);
    assertEquals(1, t.getHours());
}

@Test
public void constructorHourNegativeAbove24() {
    Time t = new Time(25, 45, 30);
    assertEquals(1, t.getHours());
}

@Test
public void constructorHourBoundary() {
    Time t = new Time(0, 45, 30);
    assertEquals(0, t.getHours());
}

@Test
public void constructorHourPositive() {
    Time t = new Time(12, 45, 30);
    assertEquals(12, t.getHours());
}

@Test
public void constructorMinutesNegativeNegative() {
    Time t = new Time(11, -1, 30);
    assertEquals(1, t.getMinutes());
}

@Test
public void constructorMinutesNegativeEdge() {
    Time t = new Time(11, 60, 30);
    assertEquals(1, t.getMinutes());
}

@Test
public void constructorMinutesBoundary() {
    Time t = new Time(11, 0, 30);
    assertEquals(0, t.getMinutes());
}

@Test
public void constructorMinutePositive() {
    Time t = new Time(11, 38, 30);
    assertEquals(38, t.getMinutes());
}

@Test
public void constructoSecondsNegativeNegative() {
    Time t = new Time(11, 24, -1);
    assertEquals(1, t.getSeconds());
}

@Test
public void constructoSecondsNegativeEdge() {
    Time t = new Time(11, 24, 60);
    assertEquals(1, t.getSeconds());
}

@Test
public void constructoSecondsBoundary() {
    Time t = new Time(11, 24, 59);
    assertEquals(59, t.getSeconds());
}

@Test
public void constructorSecondsPositive() {
    Time t = new Time(11, 24, 30);
    assertEquals(30, t.getSeconds());
}
}
```

Comment: Are  you sure you imported the correct `Time` class in your `TimeTest` class?
Furthermore, you are just testing the constructor and the getters, maybe other methods contain the bug?

Comment: UnitTest verify **desired behavior** of the code. Without *requrements* telling  **what the code is supposed to do** you cannot find bugs and UnitTests are worthless.

Comment: @KP7984 how can I test the other methods. I was only taught how to test constructors.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle in what other ways I can find the bugs in a piece of code?

Comment: *"in what other ways I can find the bugs in a piece of code?"* Sorry, but I can only quote Robert C (Unkle Bob) Martin: *"Without requirements there are no bugs, only surprising behavior."* You might do some *static code analysis* to find out if your code follows good coding standards (which are not "bug" but "code smells"). You may find possible `NullPointerExcxeption` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBounsException` but that's it. When writing unittests that look at them as *executable documentation*, not as a tool to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are helped best when you read a JUnit Tutorial like [this one](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html).
In general, you need to test all methods on correct behavior. You can do this like you did it with the constructor.

For example with your `getTimePlus(int sec)` method:
You need to create a test case where you have a `Time`-object to call `getTimePlus(int sec)` and then compare the return value with the expected and "correct" value using the `assertEquals({expectedValue}, {returnValue})` method.

When you did this with all Methods then you probably know which method got a bug but you would still need to investigate what went wrong.